# Fetch all the files in a folder but exclude all the files in a sub folder by using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a powershell script to fetch all the files in a folder but exclude all the files in a sub folder. I am using the following script, but not giving the expected results.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpath -Force -Exclude "Monthly Reports" -Recurse
```

Note: Trying to exclude the files in the sub folder "Monthly Reports"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Exclude` preforms exclusions based on the item's `.Name` property, and what you need in this case is to exclude them based on their `.FullName` property, a layer of filtering on that property is required:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpath -Force -Recurse |
    Where-Object FullName -NotMatch '[\\/]Monthly Reports[\\/]?'
```

If you want to exclude all childs of that folder but not the folder itself you can change the pattern to:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcpath -Force -Recurse |
    Where-Object FullName -NotMatch '[\\/]Monthly Reports[\\/].'
```